# Node Manager - TLS connection fails

Tags: ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c, tls1.2, nodemanager

When I try to start managed server in WebLogic, I get the following error in Node Manager log

```
TLS client initiated secure renegotiation is disabled
```

How to enable TLS renegotiation?

Comment: Try to use the 'nmap' and 'sslyze' tools to test the configuration of your SSL renegotiation. 
https://nmap.org/ 
https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze

Comment: Maybe you need to apply the Patch ID: QR92 for Bug 9412909. https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=bug&id=9412909